# Copy lines of text that match, to another

Tags: unix

In a kornshell script i want to read a file line by line

if the line contains a particular word, say "Australia",

i want to copy that whole line into a new file called Australia.txt

Thanks in advance,

Unix Novice

Comment: `grep Australia filename > Australia.txt`

Comment: @devnull: (+1) Might want to add `-w` to that (depending on the OP's exact requirements).

Answer (score 0):

You use `grep`.

`grep Australia input.txt > Australia.txt`

If you want only the word "Australia" and not, say, "Australians", then add `-w` after `grep`.  If you don't care about case, and so "australia" is OK, then add `-i` after `grep`.